# Send iMessage with iCloud or Gmail account

Tags: icloud, messages, iphone

Why can I not send iMessage with iCloud and Gmail account? I have followed all the instructions about how to turn on iMessage, add an iCloud account, and starting a conversation from iCloud messaging.

I even bought more storage for iCloud. Please help me.

Comment: What are you trying to do, send a message to whome? A mobile phone (with phone number?) or just plain text messages?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure you understand what Messages is meant to be used for. Messages is not an email client.

You can, however, receive Messages at your iCloud email and Gmail accounts. However, you don't receive them in your respective email mailboxes. You will, instead, receive those messages in the Messages application on your Mac or iOS device. Also, keep in mind that just because you can receive messages when someone sends them to your email address, that doesn't mean someone can send you an email from their iCloud or Gmail accounts and it come in via the Messages application. Again, Messages is not an email client.

For example, I enable an email address in the Messages application settings on my Macbook. My friend sends me a text via the Messages application on their iPhone. They can send the message to me either by my iPhone's cell phone number or by my email address that I added on my Macbook. That same friend opens their Gmail mailbox and sends an email to that same email address that I set up in my Messages app settings. Their email does not come to my Messages application because it's an email. Similarly, you can't email your friend at their email address and expect it to show in the Messages application.

Messages can be sent from the Messages application on one device to another Messages application on a different device.